Approximate the adjoint generator of the discretization of an SDE
Let

$d\in\mathbb N$;
$\sigma\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$;
$p\in C^1(\mathbb R^d)$ be positive with $$c:=\int p(x)\;{\rm d}x<\infty\tag1$$ and $$b:=\frac12\Sigma\nabla\ln p;$$
$(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ denote the solution of the (Langevin SDE) $${\rm d}X_t=b(X_t){\rm d}t+\sigma W_t\tag2,$$ where $(W_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a $d$-dimensional Wiener process.

The (formal) generator of $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ is given by $$Lf:=b\cdot\nabla f+\frac12\operatorname{tr}\left({\rm D}^2f\Sigma\right)\;\;\;\text{for }f\in C^2(\mathbb R^d)$$ and the (formal) $L^2$-adjoint of $L$ is $$L^\ast g:=-\nabla\cdot(gb)+\frac12\Delta(g\Sigma)\;\;\;\text{for }g\in C^2(\mathbb R^d),$$ where $\Delta(g\Sigma):=\sum_{i,j=1}^d\partial_{ij}(g\Sigma_{ij})$.

I need to simulate $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ on a computer and evaluate the adjoint of the generator $G$ of the simulated process $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ at $p$.

You might be confused reading this, cause the problem is subtle: In practice, we are generally not able to draw an exact sample from $X_t$ for a given $t>0$. Instead, we are using a simulation scheme like Euler-Maruyama method. In the latter, we are effectively simulating a Markov chain $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ with $M_0=X_0$ and $$M_n:=M_{n-1}+\Delta tb(M_{n-1})+\sqrt{\Delta t}\sigma\xi_n\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N,$$ where $\Delta t>0$ and $(\xi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an independent identically $\mathcal N(0,I_d)$-distributed process independent of $X_0$. The transition kernel of $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is $$\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;):=\mathcal N(x+\Delta tb(x),\Delta t\Sigma)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d.$$
In contrast to $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$, we are actually able to draw an exact sample from $M_n$ for any given $n\in\mathbb N_0$ (assuming we can sample from $X_0$, of course). Now, we can go back to continuous time, forming the process $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ above, by introducing holding times between the state transitions of $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$.
For example, if all of these holding times are $\operatorname{Exp}$-distributed, then the generator $G$ of $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ will precisely be the generator of $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$, which is $\kappa-\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}$.
However, this is the point where I'm uncertain if this is actually helpful. To repeat my question:

What I need to is evaluate $G^\ast p$.

The thing is: $G^\ast p$ will not be $0$. And $\Delta t$ will not be crazily small (say, around $.01$ in practice). Actual evaluation of $(G^\ast p)(y)$ at a given point $y\in\mathbb R^d$ will not be possible in my application, since this will involve computing an integral over $p$ and my assumption is that evaluation of $p$ is expensive.
So, I essentially got two ideas: Either I'm able to approximate $(G^\ast p)(y)$ in a smart way which only forces me to evaluate $p$ at $y$ (since this value will be known to me) or we need to choose a more elaborate holding time scheme.
Any idea for solving this problem is highly appreciated.
